# Rails ruby code inside xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I have xml and want add ruby code in it.

When have done `<Date><%= params[:date] %></Date>` it works ok

but when i need

```
<PTC Quantity=<%= params[:travellers]['ADT']%> >ADT</PTC>
```

after it i have got syntax error

original xml  for PTC `<PTC Quantity="1">ADT</PTC>`

How to add ruby code to nested xml values?

Comment: can you please post the error

Comment: `<PTC Quantity="<%= params[:travellers]['ADT'] %>" >ADT</PTC>` - does this work ?

Comment: " double quotes " works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to embed your ruby code inside quotes:

```
<PTC Quantity=" <%= params[:travellers]['ADT'] %> ">ADT</PTC>
```